# Detect if back button has been clicked using Perl

Tags: perl

I have seen people post about this question online but they were either using JavaScript or a different language.  Is there a way in Perl to detect if the user has clicked the back button?

```
               print "<form>";
            my $back_button_check = "Y";
            print qq{<input type=hidden name="backCheck" value="$back_button_check">};
            print qq{<button type="Button" class="inner" value="Back" onclick="history.back()">Back</button>};
            print "</form>";
```

Then on the previous page I will check for this variable.  However, this doesn't work but I'm looking to check if the user has clicked the back button because I am collecting user data.  If the user goes back a page and changes something then goes forward again, I want to update my mysql query with any changes they have made.

Is there a way in Perl to tell if the user has clicked the back button?

Comment: You won't get notified of a back-click unless you write explicit Javascript code in the HTML to detect it and notify your server code.  In the server you'll only get the resubmission of the form.

Comment: @JimGarrison ahh more Javascript. How well does Javascript mix with Perl?  Ultimately I want to write a conditional.  If back button has been clicked then run mysql query that will update database.  So If I write JS code to notify me, can that be translated into a Perl variable that can be tested for true or false?  If $back_button eq "True" then?

Comment: There’s no “mixing”.  Your Perl runs on the server, the JS on the client browser. Perl must expose an api for the JS to notify it.

Comment: use a session variable

Comment: Re "*So If I write JS code to notify me, can that be translated into a Perl variable that can be tested for true or false?*", Can Perl assign to a var a part of an HTTP request? WEll yeah. You're already doing it. The catch is that the second request will go to a different instance of the script than the first. After all, the first has already completed and exited. There is where sessions come into play.

Comment: @jhnc I read up on sessions (I've never used them before).  So I create a session and store data to a session that I can retrieve from later.  But how do I know if the back button was used?

Comment: @ikegami so I set up CGI::Session.  Are you suggesting I save user input info into sessions then edit them there before entering them into my user input database?  I'm not sure I understand.